# Symfony UID - How to save the ID as base32?

Tags: symfony, uid

I'm trying to use Symfony UID component to generate IDs. Everything works fine and I can communicate with the DB perfectly.

However, I observed that the ID is saved as binary in database. I'd like to persist the ID as base32 instead of binary.

Comment: Maybe it depends on your RDMS... Mysql? Postgre? 
I just added a `@ORM\Column(type="uuid")` to an entity. Put ` $this->uuid = uid::v4();` and ran a migration (mysql)
results: 'ALTER TABLE `my_entity_table` ADD uuid CHAR(36) NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:uuid)''

Comment: Hey @V-Light! I use MySQL, indeed. I added that meta to my entity. However, it's saved as binary inside database.